# how to highlight new record on listbox?

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie i using asp.net, I have a problem on how to automatically highlight the new added record on the listbox can anyone help me to solve this matter thanks in advance:)

```
     D
```

Comment: Do you mean select the newly added record?

Answer (score 0):

you can put your last data in one array and check it with new array and change back color of row which one is not in first array,

why you don't use *LINQ* query? Its very simple and very strong, you can get your *categoryID*  and then you just change that backcolor which one has this *categoryID*, 
 
have fun;